# export an object to csv file currently displaying data inline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, export-to-csv

I have `@people` variable contains data look exactly like:

#### What I have

```
[{"id"=>1, "name"=>"Tom", "age"=>"25"},
 {"id"=>2, "name"=>"Marry", "age"=>"27"},
 {"id"=>3, "name"=>"Jack", "age"=>"28"}]
```

and I am trying to convert the data to the CSV file, which might look like

#### What I am aiming to do

```
id | name | age
 1 | Tom  | 25
 2 | Marry| 27
 3 | Jack | 28
```

but my code generates a CSV file with displaying all of the data inline. For example:

#### What I get

```
{"id"=>1,"name"=>"Tom","age"=>25},{"id"=>2, "name"=>"Marry", 
"age"=>"27"},{"id"=>3, "name"=>"Jack", "age"=>"28"}
```

#### What I did:

`to_csv` action look like:

```
  def to_csv
    CSV.generate(option) do |csv|
      csv << column_names
      values.each do |value|
        csv << value.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
      end
    end
  end
```

I added this `respond_to` block to one of my actions:

```
respond_to do |format|
   format.html
   format.csv { 
   send_data @people.to_csv,
   filename: "export.csv",
   type: 'text/csv; charset=utf-8' 
 }
```

I am getting data(e.g `{"id"=>1,"name"=>"Tom","age"=>25 ...`) from external so I pushed that data into `@people` variable to use. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: what is @people? Isn't it a normal variable? I don't think that `to_csv` is a valid method...

Comment: @bo-oz Hi there, yeah `@people` is a normal variable, do you have any other suggestion in order to export the `@people`'s data to CSV file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to write the function differently:

```
  def to_csv(people)
    CSV.generate do |csv|
      return unless people.count > 0
      csv << people[0].keys
      people.each do |person|
        csv << person.values
      end
    end
  end
```

I suppose you could even do:

```
  def to_csv(people)
    CSV.generate do |csv|
      return unless people.count > 0
      csv << people[0].keys
      csv << people.each.map{|item| item.values}
    end
  end
```

And then call it as a function:

```
respond_to do |format|
   format.html
   format.csv { 
   send_data to_csv(@people),
   filename: "export.csv",
   type: 'text/csv; charset=utf-8' 
 }
```

Comment: You might want to add `unless people.empty?` when adding the keys otherwise it will fail if the array is empty.

Comment: fixed some bugs and followed suggestion by Kris.

Comment: The second option skips the first person

Answer (score 0):

you Don't need to do like `value.attributes.values_at(*column_names)` just you need to do `value.values` which will give you the array of values that you want to store it in CSV.

for example

```
people = [{"id"=>1, "name"=>"Tom", "age"=>"25"},
         {"id"=>2, "name"=>"Marry", "age"=>"27"},
         {"id"=>3, "name"=>"Jack", "age"=>"28"}]


def to_csv
    CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
      csv << column_names
      people.each do |person|
        csv << person.values
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i do mine, 
in my controller i added

```
respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.csv { send_data @people.to_csv }
    end
```

then

```
def self.to_csv(options = {})
      CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
        csv << column_names
        all.each do |project|
          csv << people.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
        end
      end
    end
```

then dont forget to `require 'csv'` in your config/application.rb

then you can link to your csv with something like `<%= link_to "CSV", people_path(format: "csv") %>`

Comment: This only works if @people is a ActiveModel object... it seems it isn't in this case.